# Speeding up list processing in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, scipy

I have two lists `list1` and `list2`, each of size 5000 with every entry of the lists being a `numpy.array`. I want to calculate the squares of the Euclidean distances between the elements of the lists in a fast and efficient way, i.e. I need to calculate `sum((list1[i]-list2[j])**2)` for every combination of i and j, which are thus in total 2,500,000 combinations. I currently did so by running a double loop and writing every result into a 2d `numpy.array` by means of

```
result[i,j] = sum((list1[i]-list2[j])**2)
```

but still need on my computer about 4 minutes of time. I was wondering, whether any tricks could be used to further speed the calculation up.

Comment: distance of i vs j is the same as distance of j vs i. You can cut half the time by using an inner loop that starts at the outer index

Comment: Why do you have lists of arrays? This would go much faster with 2D arrays and something like [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html).

Comment: `from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix; dist_mat = distance_matrix(list1, list2)`?

Comment: Are the component arrays all the same shape?  All 1d?

Comment: If all arrays in each list is the same shape, then a simple broadcasting ought to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on numpy (assuming your inner arrays are 1-D):

```
dist_mat = ((list1[:,None,:]-list2[:,:])**2).sum(2)
```

Note that according to your definition of distance in question, this is square of Euclidean distances. If you want the distance itself, simply take square root of this.
Otherwise, I would prefer @Quang's comment:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
dist_mat = distance_matrix(list1, list2)
```

Comment: Many thanks, these are very good responses from everyone! Especially the scipy funtions speed up the computation of the distance matrix by ages.